# Number of ways for r racers to complete the match, and one can't be finished in the first position

Tags: combinatorics, functions

I want to ask how do we represents the number of ways for r racers to finish the match with any number of ties, if a particular racer will never finish first in the race in terms of a function F.
So, the function F(r) is the total number of ways for r racers to complete the race with any number of ties. It is defined as:
$$F(r)=\sum_{p=1}^{r} p!S(r,p)$$
$S(r,n)$ denotes the number of ways of distributing r distinct objects into n identical boxes so that no box is empty.
My thought is we first consider F(r-1), and all r-1 racers finished in the first place, then the particular racer would have to be in second. And if r-1 racers give two positions, then , the particular racer could be in second or third, continuing this process, I could write:
$$1*S(r-1,1)+2*2!S(r-1,2)+3*3!S(r-1,3)+....$$
Then, I don't know how do I simplify such expression to proceed.
Thank you so much.

Comment: But isn't the correct result
$$
\text{n. of ways so that a certain racer is not first} = \text{all permutations} - \text{permutations where the racer is the first}
$$?
This would be something like $n! - (n-1)!$ ...

Comment: To be clear... it sounds like you are allowing multiple people to tie for a particular position... is that correct?  That you could have for example racers A,B and C all tie and finish in joint first place, then racer D,E tie and finish in joint fourth place.  The answer of $n!-(n-1)!$ given by @Matti is for if ties aren't possible.  The suggestion of thinking of all arrangements - arrangements where our racer is first is valid however

Comment: Thank you for you guys' comments. Yes, multiple people could be tied for a particular position, and there could be more than 1 tie. The question requires me to express this in terms of function of F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporarily ignoring the condition that our special racer be required to be in the first position, the number of results of the race (*with ties allowed*) will be the [Ordered Bell Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number) (see also: http://oeis.org/A000670):

$$a(r) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^r k! S(r,k)$$ where here $S(r,k)$ is the [Stirling Number of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

(*This is not to be confused with the usual Bell Number where the parts are unlabeled which is instead $b(r)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^rS(r,k)$*)

The number of results where our particular racer happened to finish in first?  Well, either the racer was alone in first place in which case the rest of the racers finished according to some finishing arrangement, just shifted down a position... or our racer tied in first place along with everyone else in some finishing arrangement with all others shifted down a position.  We can learn then that the number of arrangements where our racer finished first is going to be $2\cdot a(r-1)$

Our final answer can then be written succinctly with ordered bell numbers as the difference of these as

$$a(r)-2\cdot a(r-1)$$

Comment: @MathLover well spotted. Yes, that does seem reasonable.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

$f(r)= \sum \limits_{p=1}^{r-1} (2p-1) p! S(r-1,p)$

where $S(r-1,p)$ is the Stirling number of the second kind which will distribute $r-1$ distinct racers to $p$ indistinguishable groups. Then you assign those groups to specific $p$ positions in $p!$ ways..

Now $2p-1$ comes from the fact that one specific racer cannot be first but can take any place along with any of the other racer groups or positions in between them or at the end (except the first position).

For given $r$, you can use stirling number table or WolframAlpha to find $f(r)$.